# Error while opening external text file in python

Tags: python

[Code and Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECpqc.jpg)I am unable to open text file in python despite of writing correct code. Screenshot of code, error and file location is as follows[Text file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNGOU.jpg)

Comment: you have to edit carefully the question or erase it and add a new one, if you want to add code, just put it, not an image, and after all explain and code, the images

Comment: Please, Adnan, Edit the question, and put the code and the error as text

Answer (score 1):

You should enter **adnan.txt** as input, since it's a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the lines to:

```
fhand = open(raw_input("Enter a filename: "),'r')
```

And then the rest of the code

> edit

As John Smith says, be careful with the name you are trying to use, in your case seems to be **adnan.txt**

Comment: I tried entering file name as adnan.txt but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I attach here a piece of code that could work for you:

```
import os

MY_FILENAME = "adnan.txt"  # don't forget the extension

with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'MY_FILENAME'), 'r') as my_file:
    f = myfile.readlines()
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

I used `os.getcwd()` as your file seems to be in the script directory